# How to make tests with Django using real data?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd, functional-testing

Here is my situation:

We have a project that started by the wrong way, without testing. The Project uses Python 3.6* and Django 2.*. Anyway, now we are trying to code the tests and for this we are reading "**Obey the Testing Goat**" book, for Django tests.

The problem is that we are in a closed network and our system uses LDAP to make login. LDAP user is compared with our Workers database and, if the worker was not fired or in vacances, he can log in the system. For This Worker database (HR) we just have access to make queries, not inserts or updates, create, delete, etc... In resume, we have no power to manage LDAP and HR Database, just make queries. Other thing: we have no power (privileges) to create more than one database in our SQLServer. They created for us a TestDatabase. So, I always need to put **--keepdb** when I run the test command.

Also, if there is more than one database in settings, Django Tests will try to create both databases.  As we have in settings.py the HR Database (it's not managed) and the Application Database (as default), Django are trying to create both databases. But the HR database is just to do queries! How to do? We can't create workers records, just use them.

In resume: can I test with real data, making queries from a real database instead the temporary database created by Django? Can you help me, please? Any idea?

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': 'MarcoMob_TEST',
            'USER': 'MarcoMob_TESTuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'a_strong_password',
            'HOST': 'SOME_HOST',
            'PORT': '',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            },
            'TEST': {
                'NAME': 'MarcoMob_TEST',
            }
        },
        'rh': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
            'NAME': 'RH',
            'HOST': 'SOME_HOST_FOR_HR',
            'USER': 'some_user_for_hr',
            'PASSWORD': 'some_password',
            'PORT': 'port',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
            'NAME': 'MPInventoryDES',
            'USER': 'MPInventorydesuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'a_strong_password',
            'HOST': 'SOME_HOST',
            'PORT': '',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            },
        },
        'rh': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
            'NAME': 'RH',
            'HOST': 'SOME_HOST_FOR_HR',
            'USER': 'some_user_for_hr',
            'PASSWORD': 'some_password',
            'PORT': 'port',
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not setup a machine locally, and perform the tests on your local database. Testing with the real database looks to be like a terribly dangerous idea. The tests will create rows, potentially remove all data, etc. Typically it is better to separate "*development*" and "*production*" as much as possible.

Comment: Why not use mocks that return "real" data?

Comment: Thanks @Willerm. We don't have the wrights to create databases locally. For this reason they create for us the ...DES (for development) database and the ...TEST database. Anyway, HR database is just to consult... We don't have the privileges to create, drop or do something stupid in this database. Just to SELECT.

Comment: External dependencies should always be mocked in tests. It's not a question of "we can't break something". The input for a test should be hardcoded into the test and should never change so that the outcome of the test is always guaranteed to be the same. That is true for databases, requests to external APIs or even the current time. If you need test data, create them for the test.

Comment: @WilliamZimmermann You are not allowed to create a test database on your own local machine?

Comment: lncognos and @trixn, nice tips! You helped me a lot. I will search about that and in a few minutes I come back to give you a feedback. I was crazy about that since Monday!

Comment: @trixn, no... we can't do a lot of things here... 'Thanks God' that we have internet access....

Comment: @WilliamZimmermann How do they expect you to be productive while blocking access to mandatory development tools? I can't see how you could develop a decent django application without being able to have your own local database. Does that mean that every developer shares the same database during development?

Comment: @trixn. Exactly! In the beggining, for each thing we needed to ask permission (each command that brings back something, like python, pip, etc). And yes, all developers are using the same Development database, since we have limited SQLServer licenses... I know... I know... I'm just a developer.

Comment: @WilliamZimmermann You could use postgres in development if you have the permission to install that on your machine but you would have to be careful about differences in features especially with raw sql, data types and custom database functions. Or maybe you could prefix tables with a developer identifier so that every developer has his/her own tables in the same db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174891/discussion-between-william-zimmermann-and-trixn).

Comment: You could override the authentication backend for your unit tests. put a @override_settings decorator above your unit test class and override the Authentication backend setting to use Django's model backend. Then you can just use Django's model backend with full control for read/write permission. Of course, if your user model is different, then you will have to do some more work but it will still work.

Comment: @lanKirkpatrick, thanks. Yeah, this can solve one problem. But I still need to check some workers. For exemple: one of my tests is to check if a worker can access the company, putting his badge number. This check must to be done checking this HR database. I tried to put the follow decorator, but doesn't work... @mock.patch('apps.hrmob.models.Workers') and than use this way:  workers.objects.get(badge='12312312')